# Merging paired columns with duplication in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns

Goodevening, I'm working on data with two types of blood pressure (non-invasive and arterial) with different duration for each person. It has 6 columns of "id" "begin_time" "end_time" "nibp_time" "nibp_value" "abp_time" "abp_value".
I used difftime() to reduce the complexity. Time interval between "nibp_value" or "abp_value" is 5 minutes. So my data looks like below.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), 
                 nibp_time = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,2,3,NaN,NaN), 
                 nibp_value = c(80,65,80,65,80,65,80,65,95,90,83,89,NaN,NaN),
                 abp_time = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0,1), 
                 abp_value = c(68,68,66,66,70,70,73,73,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,88,84))
```

The problem is, there are missing values and I would like to merge "nibp_value" and "abp_value" according to "nibp_time" and "abp_time". If the "nibp_time" equals "abp_time", "abp_value" should be stored ("abp_value" has priority) and looks like below.

```
df2<- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
           bp_time = c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,0,1),
           bp_value = c(80,68,66,70,73,95,90,83,89,88,84))
```

So that I can apply

```
as.data.table(df2)[, dcast(.SD, id ~ bp_time, value.var = "bp_value")]
```

to make it to serial format.

I tried

```
df$bp_time <- ifelse(is.na(df$abp_time), df$nibp_time, df$abp_time)
```

In that way, the value at the time '0' of id '1' would be eliminated because abp_time has no '0' for id '1'.
Would you help me to merge properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 16.12.:**

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), 
                 nibp_time = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,2,3,NaN,NaN), 
                 nibp_value = c(80,65,80,65,80,65,80,65,95,90,83,89,NaN,NaN),
                 abp_time = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0,1), 
                 abp_value = c(68,68,66,66,70,70,73,73,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,88,84))


df[, `:=`(bp_time = ifelse(!is.na(nibp_time) & (nibp_time == 0 | is.na(abp_time)), nibp_time, abp_time),
          bp_value = ifelse(!is.na(nibp_time) & (nibp_time == 0 | is.na(abp_time)), nibp_value, abp_value))]

df2 = unique(df[, c(1,6,7)], by=c("id", "bp_time"))
```

**Output:**

```
> df2
    id bp_time bp_value
 1:  1       0       80
 2:  1       1       68
 3:  1       2       66
 4:  1       3       70
 5:  1       4       73
 6:  2       0       95
 7:  2       1       90
 8:  2       2       83
 9:  2       3       89
10:  3       0       88
11:  3       1       84
```

**Validation:**

```
df_check<- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
                      bp_time = c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,0,1),
                      bp_value = c(80,68,66,70,73,95,90,83,89,88,84))
> df2 == df_check
        id bp_time bp_value
 [1,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
 [2,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
 [3,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
 [4,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
 [5,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
 [6,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
 [7,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
 [8,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
 [9,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
[10,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
[11,] TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. It makes a similar  results but   your first solution eliminate the id "3" because it does not have NIBP value. ..   updated solution has duplicated and is abp_time and nibp_time is same, only abp_value should remain and nibp_value is deleted... . id should not be removed because the bp is belong to each ids..

Comment: I  used your updated solution and made another dataframe with "id" "final_value" and "final_time" from it. Using unique() for the result, I get what I wanted. Millions of thanks!!!!!

Comment: oh.................... I'm sorry I confused you........................ it's not what I wanted. I want to make df to df2, not making df3 from df and df2.  T_T

Comment: Thank you a lot for your update. I think your solution is the best since my real data is scarce.   Thanks!